# Assembly line: [address offset](register,register,value)

Tags: assembly, x86-64

what does this assembly code mean exactly?

```
   0x000000000040075d <+393>:   mov    %dl,-0x70(%rbp,%rax,1)
```

I know the meaning of let's say

```
mov    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
```

It would be move data from the address of %rbp offset by -50 to %rax.

But I have no idea what does the 3 argumens in the bracket mean